# .NET Web api 2 stops working after sometime in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I have two web API project **DLLs** in one solution.

**Structure of my Project Solution:**

In my solution, the projects are located as follows:

1) Base Solution

2) Base Web API

3) Module Web API

***Hence, my solution is something like a BASE solution which contains many MODULES. Each Modules can contain its own Web APIs. Also, my Base Solution contains its own Web API***

This is our structure.

**My Problem:**

It is working fine  in my local run solution. When I host it to the IIS, it is working for few hours and then it stops working by throwing the error message "Error 404 found". When I try to access through URL directly which is something like "http://127.0.0.1:51/Products/Get", not working.

**Visual Studio version:**

Visual Studio Professional - 2015

**IIS Version:**

IIS - 7.5.7600

**My approach:**
I have a simple project which simulates this scenario. It has the same problem with my original project.

**Web API For Base Module:**

**WepApiConfig under App_Start:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Base API Controller:**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs For Module Web API:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultModuleApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/module/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Module API Controller:**

```
public class ModulesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

**NOTE from the above code:**

The difference between the two APIConfig files is :

**For Module Code:**

```
routeTemplate: "api/module/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

**For Base Code:**

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

**Global.asax:**

```
namespace BaseSln
{
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        var typesWithMyAttribute =
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetLoadableTypes().Where(t1 => t1.Name == "WebApiConfig"
                            && t1.GetMethod("Register") != null
                            && t1.GetMethod("Register").IsStatic)
            select new { Type = t, MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Register") };

        //register all the Routes
        foreach (var type in typesWithMyAttribute)
        {
            var mi = type.MethodInfo;
            Action<HttpConfiguration> action = null;
            try
            {
                action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<HttpConfiguration>), mi) as Action<HttpConfiguration>;
            }
            catch
            {
                //ignore the errors for now... should be handled somewhere else or logged.
            }

            if (action != null) GlobalConfiguration.Configure(action);
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I tried with the above project:

After hosting in IIS, I tried to access the path which is something like this:

**For Base API:**

http://localhost:51600/api/Values/Get

**Returns:**

```
value1
value2
```

**For Module API**

http://localhost:51600/api/Modules/Get

**Returns:**

```
value1
value2
```

**My problem:**

After sometime, when I try to access the same link, I am unable to get that. It says

```
status 404. Not Found
```

I have been working on this issue for 3 days, and I couldn't resolve the problem.

I have searched many articles in stackoverflow, but no luck.

Kindly help me to get rid off from this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd take a look in the try/catch block you have there that is swallowing any errors. Try logging somewhere and see if it's in there.

Comment: How does it stop working? Is the AppPool stopping? Is the site in IIS stopping? How are you restarting it? (do you recycle the app pool or restart the site in IIS or similar?)

Comment: can you solve this problem, because i have this problem too

Comment: hey is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` in the Base Solution if you have all the routes for both the Base Web API and the Module Web API?

Comment: Yes. I checked and it works fine for sometime after hosting in IIS. But after sometime, it stops working. Which means at this part `if (action != null) GlobalConfiguration.Configure(action);` ?